# How i can catch exception inside aspect(@Before) and write correct httpResponse to client?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webflux, aop, project-reactor

my code now is:

```
    @Override
    @Before("@annotation(demo.webflux.test.PermittedByRole) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public Object logBeforeMethodCall(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        var signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        var method = signature.getMethod();
        PermittedByRole annotation = method.getAnnotation(getAnnotationClass());
        String operation = annotation.operation();
        return testService.testAction(operation)
                .filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(""))))
                .subscribe();
    }
```

TestService is:

```
    public Mono<Boolean> testAction(String operation) {
        log.info("test payload");
        return Mono.just(false);
    }
```

Example of using my aspect:

```
    @PermittedByRole(operation = "test")
    @GetMapping(value = "/oac")
    public Mono<TestObject> base() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return Mono.just(new TestObject().setFieldOne("one").setFieldTwo("two"));
    }
```

I tried to handle exception by custom WebFilter, but it is not working. I get org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException.

Comment: the `subscribe` method returns a `Disposable` and as a result your pointcut is returning a `Disposable`. In addition, if you call subscribe but don't implement the error callback and your `Mono` returns an error then a `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` will be thrown. This is probably the error you are currently seeing

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen thank you for answer. Can you show please how i can fixed it, if i need to return 403 from aspect, if boolean not true?